# Delay Loading of JS Script

Tags: javascript, wordpress, delay

I am trying to delay the loading of a JS script on WordPress for 3 seconds, i.e., I want the page to load and then after 3s load the JS script.

I have tried including "setTimeout" without luck.

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
  {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
  n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
  if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
  n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
  t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
  'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
  fbq('init', 'xxxxxx');
  fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
  src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=xxxxxx&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/>
</noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Comment: Why do you need to wait three seconds?

Comment: Please don't sign your posts, your posts are already attributed to you. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dynamically load the javascript.
See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

I would recommend this answer extended with setTimeout (untested):

```
<script type="module">
  setTimeout(()=>{
  import('hello.mjs').then(module => {
      module.hello('world');
    });
  }, 3000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you. Just put your javascript inside this code.

```
  document.onreadystatechange = function () {
     if (document.readyState == "complete") {
        setTimeout(function(){ 
          // document is ready. Load your javascript here.
        }, 3000); //javascript will load 3 seconds after your page has fully loaded
     }
 }
```

[onreadystatechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState)